# Run Systemd Service After Display Manager

Tags: systemd, gnome, systemd-service

I have a script that changes some Gnome settings which I want to run on startup. The script itself works fine when I run it manually, but I get the following error when I run it as a systemd service:

```
● startup-user.service - Startup Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/startup-user.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-02-05 13:03:48 UTC; 21s ago
    Process: 1948 ExecStart=/data/startup-user.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1948 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 22ms

Feb 05 13:03:48 debian systemd[1]: Started Startup Service.
Feb 05 13:03:48 debian gsettings[1950]: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Feb 05 13:03:48 debian gsettings[1953]: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Feb 05 13:03:48 debian gsettings[1956]: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Feb 05 13:03:48 debian startup-user.sh[1959]: Error connecting: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Feb 05 13:03:48 debian systemd[1]: startup-user.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 05 13:03:48 debian systemd[1]: startup-user.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Here is the script file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled false
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen Brightness '<int32 100>'
```

And here's the service unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Startup Service
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/data/startup-user.sh
User=user

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

This is the first time I've worked with systemd services, and I don't know much about display managers or whatever else is involved here, but I assume that if my service is starting after `graphical.target`, then the display manager should be started and all necessary variables should be set. I've also tried `After=gdm.service`, and I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to have `graphical.target` for both `After=` and `WantedBy=`, but if I remove it from `WantedBy=` then the service doesn't run at all.

In case you're wondering and/or it makes a difference, this is for a live system I'm building with [Debian Live](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianLive). Instead of using a persistence partition, I want to run this script every time I boot up so it can do some basic configuration. The script file resides on a separate ext4 partition mounted at `/data`, so I can modify the script file whenever I want to change the settings.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here isn't just "before/after", it's also that **not all state is global.** Just because X11 has already been started doesn't mean all processes automatically gain knowledge of what $DISPLAY to use, and the same applies to the session D-Bus socket address. (Especially not when you remember that there could be *multiple* sessions, each having a different $DISPLAY value.) Instead, this is limited to the process tree starting with the display manager itself and its children.

(System services *in general* are not meant to poke around in user sessions.)

Session components should be run by the session itself – either through XDG Autostart (using .desktop files in `~/.config/autostart/` and the corresponding /etc/xdg location) or through systemd *user* services (`~/.config/systemd/user`) or through the Xsession script if X11 is used (`~/.xprofile`, `~/.xsession`). That way they always run at the correct time and always inherit the correct environment.